# cannot restart correctly ubuntu after use docker python "no space left on device" , no memory available on peripheric

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

Today i tried to create a docker of the final version of my project(my project has a size of 3.2 Go) with the command "docker build --tag my-python-app". I had several problems during the manipulation : i ran the command docker. it several times because in the file "Dockerfile", i specified the wrong python and wrong pip. Anyway, now i have "no space left on device" and my screen is blinking.

For the moment, I tried an autoremove, but still not enough space.

Someone has an idea of what is happening?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think that tagging a docker build will create another image, which means you are having a lot image copies in your disk. You can check which images you have with the command `docker images`

Comment: I already checked, and this is empty. I can't find the ID of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
When you build your docker, and this print an error, it doesn't delete intermediate containers created in the folder /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff (my error was in the dockerfile, where i precised the wrong python and the wrong pip), and this folder is saved in the peripherical part of the memory. So if you take all the memory, your computer is full of bug (screen, keyword, ...) and you can only use your terminal.
To resolver the problem you have to delete these folders

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to remove unused Docker images or containers?

You can see the list of images by running:

`docker images`

And you can remove them like:

`docker rmi <id>`

The process is fairly similar for the containers:

`docker ps -a`

And:

`docker rm <id>`

Be careful not to remove used containers or images.

Comment: display images doesn't display anything. That is even more weird. It says now "no memory available on peripheral" .

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Docker service or restart your machine? You may have better luck posting this question on another board like [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker image ls` to see if you have any images that you can delete to free up space.

If you find images that you do not need, you can remove them individually or all at once.  Run `docker image prune -h` to display the options for removing images.

Comment: docker image ls doesn't print any images, like if there were nothing but the memory is full... 
However, when i use the command df -h, I see that the disc /dev/sdb3 is 100% used, I am looking to this way for the moment

Comment: That makes sense. If you look at your docker settings, you might be able to increase the space allocated to docker.